# Swift: Iterating through String when I receive a “fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value”

Tags: swift

I'm currently making a Decimal to Binary calculator in SWIFT and have run into this error while iterating through a string. My calculator only works if a decimal is included currently so I've been trying to fix that using the .rangeOfString Operator . The error ONLY occurs when I give the function a number without a decimal - in this case 31

```
import UIKit

var Input : String = "31";

func Splitter(UserInput : String) -> (Interger: Int, Decimal: Double, DecimalLength : Int)
{
var DecimalPortion : String = ""
var IntergerPortion : String = ""
var AfterDecimal : Bool = false
var DecimalLength : Int
var HasDecimal : Bool


if UserInput.rangeOfString(".") != nil
{
    **for character in UserInput** //error is thrown here.
    {
        if AfterDecimal == true
        {
            DecimalPortion += String(character)
        }

        if character == "."
        {
            AfterDecimal = true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift deals correctly with Unicode strings and string indices are not what you think they are.  Additionally the `rangeOfString()` function returns a range which you don't seem to be using effectively.  Here is another approach:

```
func splitter (input : String) -> (String?, String?) {
  let split = input.componentsSeparatedByString (".")
  switch split.count {
  case 1: return (split[0], nil)
  case 2: return ((split[0].isEmpty ? nil : split[0]), 
                  (split[1].isEmpty ? nil : split[1]))
  default: return (nil, nil)
  }
}


 15> splitter("12.34")
$R5: (String?, String?) = { 0 = "12", 1 = "34" }

 16> splitter("12")
$R6: (String?, String?) = { 0 = "12", 1 = nil  }

 17> splitter("12.")
$R7: (String?, String?) = { 0 = "12", 1 = nil  }

 18> splitter(".12")
$R9: (String?, String?) = { 0 = nil,  1 = "12" }
```

Answer (score 0):

i don't know what is the wrong but i tried this

```
var characters = Array(UserInput)

for value in characters
{
    println(value);

    if AfterDecimal == true
    {
        DecimalPortion += String(value)
    }

    if value == "."
    {
        AfterDecimal = true
    }
}
```